# Why does argument 'Delegate' accept only RoutedEventHandler delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, action

This works fine:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(DataGrid),    
      DataGrid.SelectionChangedEvent,    
      new RoutedEventHandler(ScrollToSelectedItem));

void ScrollToSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

This compiles but gives at runtime the exception: *Handler type is mismatched*:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(DataGrid),    
         DataGrid.SelectionChangedEvent,       
         new Action<object, RoutedEventArgs>(    
         (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e1) =>    
         ScrollToSelectedItem(sender, e1, false)));

  void ScrollToSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, bool jump)
```

The third parameter of `RegisterClassHandler` is declared as `Delegate handler`.

Is it implicitly assumed that the handler is not only a delegate but a `RoutedEventHandler` delegate?
Then why has `RegisterClassHandler` not a more accurate signature?

EDIT
just discovered that I can solve this via:

```
RoutedEventHandler htrue = (o, ea) => ScrollToSelectedItem(o, ea, true);
RoutedEventHandler hfalse = (o, ea) => ScrollToSelectedItem(o, ea, false);
void ScrollToSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, bool jump)
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(DataGrid),     
        DataGrid.SelectionChangedEvent, hfalse);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because two different delegates have the same signature doesn't make them the same, for the same reason that the following two types aren't the same:

```
public class Foo { public int n; }
public class Bar { public int n; }
```

You can't assign a `Foo` to a `Bar` just because they have the same instance fields.

`Action` is a type, just like `RoutedEventHandler`, and there is no implicit conversion between them.

> Then why has RegisterClassHandler not a more accurate signature?

As to why it doesn't have a more defined signature, I couldn't say, I didn't design the class.  It does sound like it's not very well designed though, given your confusion.  It probably *should* have had a specific delegate as the required parameter.

Comment: Would it be possible to (implicitly) convert `Action<object, RoutedEventArgs>` to `RoutedEventHandler`?

Comment: @Gerard No, it is not.

Comment: @Servy, `public static implicit operator RoutedEventHandler(Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> act)` -- not that it's necessarily a great idea, but hey...

Comment: @BrianS Go ahead, try and compile a program using that.  I'll wait.

Comment: @Servy, That's what I get for posting without thinking, I guess. (And rarely defining conversions, since they rarely improve my code's readability.) For the reader: conversions must be defined within their enclosing type, so my previous comment would need to be defined within `RoutedEventHandler`... which is (a) a `delegate` so that can't happen, and (b) already defined in a DLL so that can't happen.

Comment: @brian,servy be that as it may, there is a workaround, see my edit.

Comment: @Gerard That's still explicitly typing the delegate as a `RoutedEventHandler`.  There really isn't much of anything about that that's different than the earlier code.  As always, there are a million different ways to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate (uppercase) is a class.  delegate (lowercase) is a type.

Action<> returns a delegate (lowercase) which does not cast to Delegate (uppercase) as far as I can tell.

Comment: RoutedEventHandler is a lc-delegate and works fine when passed in for the uc-Delegate parameter. `Action<object, RoutedEventArgs>` is also a lc-delegate, at first sight of the same type as RoutedEventHandler (but not really according to Servy's answer).

Comment: @Gerard No, it's not the same type.  It's an entirely different type.  It just happens to have the same signature; that's very different.